# where is the detail disclosure button image stored?

Tags: ios, icons

Where is the actual image file for the detail disclosure button (and other similar icons) used in iOS for `UITableView` stored on the device itself (or for the iOS simulator on a Mac)? I know I can find the icon/s with a web search, but the image files don't seem to have the transparency preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the PNGs used by the operating system using [UIKit Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor).